# Form errors not displaying in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show form errors on create for `list_items`. The form is implemented in the `show` template located in `lists` views, so it's not in it's mother view location. So it should be possible for customers to add a list_item through the list's show template and also output the errors right there, if something went wrong.

`list_items/form`

```
<%= form_with(model: resource, url: customer_list_list_items_path(customer, list), method: :post, data: { turbo: false }) do |form| %>
  <%= render 'errors', resource: resource %>
  <div class="field mb-3">
    <%= form.label :text, t('activerecord.attributes.list.name'), class: 'form-label', style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_area :text, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions mt-3 mb-3">
    <%= form.submit t('buttons.add'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

form here, users should be able to add list_items for the current shown list. This is implemented in the following show view for lists

`lists_items/errors`

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation" class='alert alert-danger'>
    <h3>
      <%=
          I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
          count: resource.errors.count,
          resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
        %>
    </h3>
    <ul>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`lists/show`

```
<%= link_to I18n.t('buttons.back'), :back, class: 'btn btn-light mb-3' %>
<div class="text-center">
  <h3><%= @list.name %></h3>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p><%= @list.description %></p>
    <%= render 'actions', customer: @customer, list: @list %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    <%= render 'list_items/form', resource: @list_item, list: @list, customer: @customer %>
  </div>
</div>
<% @list.list_items.reverse_order.each do |list_item| %>
  <%= render 'list_items/list_item', customer: @customer, list: @list, list_item: list_item %>
<% end %>
```

`lists_controller.rb`

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :set_customer
  before_action :set_list_items, only: :show
  before_action :approve_customers_list_access, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  # GET /lists or /lists.json
  def index
    @lists = List.all
  end

  # GET /lists/1 or /lists/1.json
  def show
    @list_item = ListItem.new
  end

  # GET /lists/new
  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  # GET /lists/1/edit
  def edit; end

  # POST /lists or /lists.json
  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    @list.customer_id = @customer.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.save
        format.html { redirect_to customer_list_url(@customer, @list), notice: t('flash.list.create') }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lists/1 or /lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.update(list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to customer_list_url(@customer, @list), notice: t('flash.list.edit') }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /lists/1 or /lists/1.json
  def destroy
    @list.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customer_lists_url, notice: t('flash.list.delete') }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_customer
    @customer = Customer.find_by id: params[:customer_id]
  end

  # lists should be (by now!) only be shown to customers, that actually created the list
  # [Maybe] Add functionality to invite other customers to list
  def approve_customers_list_access
    list = List.find_by id: params[:id]
    unless customer_signed_in? && list.customer_id == current_customer.id || admin_signed_in?
      redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
    end
  end

  def set_list_items
    @list_items = ListItem.where(list_id: params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :description, :customer_id)
  end

  def list_item_params
    params.require(:list_item).permit(:text, :customer_id, :id)
  end
end
```

I am setting a new list_item @list_item in the show method.

`list.rb` Model

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer

  has_many :list_items, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

`list_items_controller.rb`

```
class ListItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list_and_customer
  before_action :set_list_item, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  # GET /list_items or /list_items.json
  def index
    @list_items = ListItem.all
  end

  def new
    @list_item = ListItem.new
  end

  # GET /list_items/1/edit
  def edit; end

  # POST /list_items or /list_items.json
  def create
    @list_item = ListItem.new(list_item_params)
    @list_item.customer_id = params[:customer_id]
    @list_item.list_id = params[:list_id]

    if @list_item.save
      redirect_to customer_list_path(@customer, @list), notice: t('flash.list_item.create')
    else
      # I know something about this is wrong, since it eventually renders the  list_items new to the page and gives me an error for missing custome_id and list_id
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /list_items/1 or /list_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @list_item.update(list_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to customer_list_path(@customer, @list), notice: t('flash.list_item.edit') }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /list_items/1 or /list_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @list_item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_back fallback_location: customer_list_url(@customer, @list), notice: t('flash.list_item.delete')
      end
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_list_item
    @list_item = ListItem.find_by id: params[:id]
  end

  def set_list_and_customer
    @list = List.find_by id: params[:list_id]
    @customer = Customer.find_by id: params[:customer_id]
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def list_item_params
    params.require(:list_item).permit(:text, :list_id, :customer_id)
  end
end
```

`list_item.rb` Model

```
class ListItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :customer

  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

And my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)' do

    # customer resources
    resources :customers do
      resources :lists do
        resources :list_items
      end
    end

    # root_path
    root 'main#index'
  end
end
```

The basic path for a list would look like
`/customers/:customer_id/lists/:id`

And for the rendered form
`/customers/:customer_id/lists/:list_id/list_items/new`

If you need some more information, let me know!

Comment: You really should look into shallow nesting. "Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep." https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: There is one other big problem -you're using `@list_item = ListItem.find_by id: params[:id]` instead of  `@list_item = ListItem.find(params[:id])` . The later wil raise an exception if the record can't be found instead of letting execution continue and blow up with a NoMethodError since you're allowing a nil value.  If you're going to display/update/destroy something you better make sure that it actually exists!

Comment: And as for the core part of the question - can you display the form and errors on the show view of the parent resource? Sure you can - but it means that your `create` action must do all the work of setting up the instance variables/locals for that view. There is nothing that actually explicitly ties a view to a controller action or a model to a controller. Its all just convention to make your life easier. You as the programmer can still break the conventions in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: There are better ways to do what you're looking to do though such as using `accepts_nested_attributes` to let you create/update/destroy the nested items together with the parent. Or by using AJAX.